# oracle SQL : getting DEPT by min and max sums

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 working subqueries that checks what are the min and max SUMS in all departments (DEPTNO). Table EMP and DEPT has DEPTNO cells

```
(SELECT min(sum(e.SAL)) FROM EMP e GROUP by e.DEPTNO);
(SELECT max(sum(e.SAL)) FROM EMP e GROUP by e.DEPTNO);
```

How to check what is the DEPTNO for min- and max- subquery?
My code is with ERROR:

```
SELECT d.DEPTNO 
FROM DEPT d 
WHERE sum(e.SAL) = (SELECT max(sum(e.SAL)) FROM EMP e GROUP by d.DEPTNO);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the department withe the max sum, you can use `rownum` or `row_number()`:

```
select ed.*
from (select e.deptno, sum(e.sal) as sums,
             row_number() over (order by sum(e.sal) desc) as seqnum
      from emp e
      group by e.deptno
     ) ed
where seqnum = 1;
```

In Oracle 12g+, this can also be written as:

```
      select e.deptno, sum(e.sal) as sums,
             row_number() over (order by sum(e.sal) desc) as seqnum
      from emp e
      group by e.deptno
      order by sum(e.sal) desc
      fetch first 1 row only;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it using `cte`

```
with salsums as (select deptno, sum(sal) salsum from emp group by deptno)
, maxandmin as (select max(salsum) maxsal, min(salsum) minsal from salsums)
select deptno 
from salsums cross join maxandmin
where salsum = maxsal or salsum = minsal
```

Comment: this is cute, I like it.

Comment: this works, but I never use "with..." :/... but I will rebuild it my way, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is harder than it looks at first.  This is how I ended up getting it to work but I like @vkp's answer more.

```
with sums as
(
  SELECT DEPTNO, SUM(SAL) AS SSAL
  FROM EMP
  GROUP BY DEPTNO
), mm as
(
  SELECT DEPTNO, SSAL, MIN(SSAL) OVER () as MIN_SSAL, MAX(SSAL) OVER () as MAX_SSAL
  FROM SUMS
)
SELECT 'MIN', DEPTNO, SSAL FROM mm WHERE SSAL=MIN_SSAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MAX', DEPTNO, SSAL FROM mm WHERE SSAL=MAX_SSAL
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/410c8/8

Comment: I think you need something like `HAVING sum(e.SAL) = MIN(sum(sal))`